# SSAS, Calculation, Gender Standarized Rate

Tags: ssas, calculation, rate

First we get the crude rate which is cancer count/population count * 100,000, since cancer count might relate to the population of male/female ration, so need to turn the crude rate to standardized rate, so later we can compare rate among different populations, here the assumption of standard population of ratio of `Female:Male = 51:49`.

So the Gender Standardized Rate is:

```
Female crude rate * female percentage + Male crude rate * male percentage =
671.7 * 0.51 + 716.7 * 0.49 = 693.7
```

So for total standardized rate it will be 693.7, the rest standardized rate will be same as crude rate.

The question is how to implement it? How should I define it in Calculation like `if currentmember.level = total then ... else [crude rate]`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to ignore Undifferentiated, and calculate Satnsarized. You could try to use expression like below to see whether it will work or not

with member[Measures].[SalesCalc2] AS
(
IIF([Product].[Category].CurrentMember=[Product].[Category].&[3],"0",[Measures].[Internet Sales Count])
)

member[Measures].[SalesCalc3] AS
[Measures].[SalesCalc2] *[Measures].[Internet Sales Count]

select [Product].[Category].[Category] on rows, {[Measures].[Internet Sales Count],[Measures].[SalesCalc2] ,[Measures].[SalesCalc3] } on columns  from 
[Analysis Services Tutorial]

[image]

You could refer to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f6a7381-9dd3-422e-9b8a-23e1f198890f/mdx-excluding-dimension-members-from-the-measure-calculation?forum=sqlanalysisservices) for details

Zoe

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use SCOPE in calculation.
The purpose of using SCOPE is to do the calculation first, which is
Female crude rate * female percentage and Male crude rate * male percentage 
then add them together, so the formula is
671.7 * 0.51 + 716.7 * 0.49 = 693.7

Please refer to the following link for steps to implement it:
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/05/29/aggregating-the-result-of-an-mdx-calculation-using-scoped-assignments/